# Algorithm to convert int to 6 character alphanumeric string

Tags: c#, algorithm, int

I have an ID field that automatically increments by 1 when a new record is added. Rather than use the numeric ID as is, I would like to convert it to a 6 character string made up of 0-9A-Z (no lowercase letters) with the following format:

```
A00000
```

The numbers should increment from 0-9 then A-Z.

**Examples**

If I were to encode the number `7` for example, it should return:

```
A00007
```

If I encode the number `13` it should return:

```
A0000D
```

If I encode the number `36` it should return:

```
A00010
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically it's a base 36 number?

Comment: @phoog I've tried some base 36 encoding with some luck but I was curious to see if there's a better solution out there. And yes, that should have been a 36. Typo fixed.

Comment: I wrote some code to do that kind of stuff in answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885582/c-sharp-shorten-int-into-case-sensitive-code/8886171#8886171

Comment: @SystemDown Basically, yes.

Comment: Suggestion: Add 604661760 to the integer value ( = 10 * 36 ^ 5 ), then encode in base 36.

Comment: @phoog That's brilliant! If you write up your comment as an answer I'll be happy to upvote and accept.

Comment: @JasonTowne Thank you.  I've added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestion: Add 604661760 to the integer value.  That's the base-10 value of `A00000`, interpreted as a base-36 number ( = 10 * 36 ^ 5 ).

Then encode the result in base 36.

Depending on your data range, you might want to promote the `int` to a `long` before adding 604661760.

Comment: Good idea with your `int` vs. `long` suggestion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is conversion from a base 10 number to a base 36 number. Here's an algorithm for conversion from base 10 to base K. Modify it to suit your needs:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/toBaseK.html